# Direct conversion of Keplerian orbital elements to Equatorial coordinate system

Tags: orbital-elements, simulation

In the context of a computer simulation of satellites that orbit earth, I am looking for a (accurate) **method for converting Keplerian orbital elements directly to Equatorial coordinate system**.

The simulation describe the orbit of a satellite by a set of Keplerian [orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) in order to determine an orbit and move the satellite along it.
However, in order to show the satellite position graphically, the orbital elements are converted into an [equatorial coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system). This allow a very simple projection of the satellite location on a 2D map.

Currently the orbital elements are converted to equatorial coordinates by (1) converting the orbital elements into Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) as described in the following link in the [Computing Position from Orbital Elements](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/determining-orbital-position-at-a-future-point-in-time) section and than (2) converting the Cartesian coordinates into Equatorial coordinate system. However, the double conversion cause lost of precision.

It "feels" as might be a direct way to convert orbital elements to equatorial coordinate, since both use angles it might be possible to transfer the orbital elements representation into equatorial one, but I am yet to find it.

is it possible to convert this:

[image: Keplerian orbital elements]

directly to this:

[image: Equatorial coordinate system]

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This paper by Rene Schwarz could be useful in this regard - it covers the direct conversion from Keplerian Orbital Elements (a, e, i, etc.) to Cartesian State Vectors (R and Rdot, which is actually X/Y/Z and X./Y./Z.)

It can be found [here.](https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M001-Keplerian_Orbit_Elements_to_Cartesian_State_Vectors.pdf)

The steps are enumerated there as follows, but the equations are substantial and transcribing each here would run a high risk of introducing transcription errors.

> 1. Calculate or set M(t)
> 2. Solve Kepler’s Equation M(t) = E(t) − e sin E for the eccentric anomaly E(t) with an appropriate method numerically, e.g. the Newton–Raphson method
> 3. Obtain the true anomaly ν(t)
> 4. Use the eccentric anomaly E(t) to get the distance to the central body
> 5. Obtain the position and velocity vector o(t) and o˙(t), respectively, in the orbital frame (z-axis perpendicular to orbital plane, x-axis pointing to periapsis of the orbit)
> 6. Transform o(t) and o˙(t) to the inertial frame in bodycentric (in case of the Sun as central body: heliocentric) rectangular coordinates r(t) and r˙(t) with the rotation matrices Rx(φ) and Rz(φ) using the transformation sequence

Comment: @uhoh Actually kind of curious with this paper - would you happen to know if this only works for a two-body system?

Comment: Keplerian ↔ 2 body and actually they are reducible to a one-body problem. For anything that involves more than to point-like or spherically symmetric objects, anything with Kepler in it won't work. There are things called "hierarchical" multi-body orbits like  a close binary orbiting another single or binary star at a great distance. In those cases you can treat them *approximately* as separate Kepler orbits, but it's not exact.

Comment: @jos thanks for the answer. I actually know the paper you linked, and as written in the question, allready implemented orbital elemnts -> cartesian coordinates, and cartesian coordinates -> equatorial coordinates. however I am not happy with it since the double conversion hurt the precision. I was hoping to have a direct method: orbital elemnts -> equatorial coordinates, It seems posibble. If I understand correctlly your answer does not offer such direct conversion?